# How to make a "$and" and "$or" query together in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have MongoDB Collection and my requests are as below

This works: (Returns only with `frequency:1` records)

```
http://localhost:3000/words?frequency=1
```

This works: (Returns only with `difficulty:2` records)

```
http://localhost:3000/words?difficulty=2
```

This works but not that I want

```
http://localhost:3000/words?frequency=1&difficulty=2
```

> This query not returns with that has both `frequency=1` **and**
> `difficulty=2` values. But I want to only get has **both**
> `frequency=1`, `difficulty=2`values.
>
> This query should return only `"word":"first"`, but returns with `"word":"first"` and `"word":"fourth"`

**Sample MongoDB Collection:**

```
{
    "word": "first",
    "frequency": 1,
    "difficulty": 2
},
{
    "word": "second",
    "frequency": 1,
    "difficulty": 1
},
{
    "word": "third",
    "frequency": 2,
    "difficulty": 1
},
{
    "word": "fourth",
    "frequency": 2,
    "difficulty": 2
},
```

And this is my query:

```
const difficulty = req.query.difficulty;
const frequency = req.query.frequency;
Words.find( { $or: [ { difficulty: difficulty }, { frequency: frequency }, { $and: [ { difficulty: difficulty }, { frequency: frequency } ] } ] } )
```

I am trying to fix this since yesterday but I couldn't solve it, thanks for your helps (sorry for my english)

**Solved:** Solved with conditions

Answer (score 0):

> I want to only get has both frequency=1, difficulty=2values

Your query won't work as expected, because you have given all the option in $or and $and conditions. So even if you send different params in the API call, it will check like this:
eg:

For: http://localhost:3000/words?frequency=1&difficulty=2

Your query would be:

```
Words.find( { $or: [ { difficulty: 2 }, { frequency: 1 }, { $and: [ { difficulty: 2 }, { frequency: 1 } ] } ] } )
```

Which is searching for 
 - either { difficulty: 2 } 
 - or { frequency: 1 }
 - or { difficulty: 2 } and { frequency: 1 }

That's why you get mix results.

Here's what you can do...

check the query params in the controller and based on that send different queries to the DB and get exact data.

for eg,

For: http://localhost:3000/words?frequency=1&difficulty=2

Try this:

```
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    {
      frequency: 1
    },
    {
      difficulty: 2
    }
  ]
});
```

And for

http://localhost:3000/words?frequency=1

http://localhost:3000/words?difficulty=2

```
db.collection.find( { $or: [ { difficulty: difficulty }, { frequency: frequency } ] } )
```

Here's an example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/DmdxOx6wc8K

Comment: Ok, let me have a look.

Comment: So.. I should create 2 function for queries in my controller ?, Can't I do that in one function ?

Comment: Yes, or you can have a flag set in controller and based on that just change the query of query controller.

Comment: Not worked, when I created function for each query only `http://localhost:3000/words?frequency=1&difficulty=1`this works. `http://localhost:3000/words?frequency=1` or `http://localhost:3000/words?difficulty=1` not working, returns with 0 result :(

Comment: @AhmetZeybek You might want to use $and by default. But if *filter_operator=OR* is found in query, use replace the query with $or. Like http://localhost:3000/words?frequency=1&difficulty=1 for using $and operator, and http://localhost:3000/words?frequency=1&difficulty=1&filter_operator=OR for $or.

Comment: Can you post your controller code? That I asked you to do?

Comment: I solved with checking query values if null or not, created 3 conditions to controller, writing from phone sorry, thanks for help @captain

Comment: Great, what were you doing wrong, when you previously commented?
Was my answer any helpful?

Comment: If my helped you solve the problem, do upvote and accept the answer in order to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the query in a single $or operator.

To return records with both frequency=1, difficulty=2 values, you have to use $and operator.

And as per MongoDB docs, it provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma separated list of expressions.
So you can directly use:

```
Words.find({
   frequency: 1,
   difficulty: 2
});
```

But for *AND Queries With Multiple Expressions Specifying the Same Operator*, refer [MongoDB Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#and-queries-with-multiple-expressions-specifying-the-same-operator)

Comment: I solved thanks,  but your answer was not solution,  I already know that, read again my problem